# How can I refactor this code? (JavaScript) My purpose is the execution of reload() only 3 times

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, frontend, refactoring

How to deal with this case? Nothing similar I couldn't find. I need to reload my page 3 times after 30sec. (the conditions of a game) After the 3d time, reload() shouldn't work. Can I do it using a for loop? Are there any variants?

```
if(!sessionStorage.getItem('refreshed')) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('refreshed', true);
        //this piece of code is repeated too may times
        setTimeout(() => {
            result.innerHTML = " "
            location.reload()
         }  
        ,
        30000
        )
        
    } 
  

   else if(!sessionStorage.getItem('refreshed2')) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('refreshed2', true);
        //and here...
        setTimeout(() => {
            result.innerHTML = " "
            location.reload()
         }  
        ,
        30000
        )
        
    } 
 
   
   else if(!sessionStorage.getItem('refreshed3')) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('refreshed3', true);
        //and here...
        setTimeout(() => {
            result.innerHTML = " "
            location.reload()
         }  
        ,
        30000
        )
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (sessionStorage.getItem('n') === null)
  sessionStorage.setItem('n', 3);

while (+sessionStorage.getItem('n') > 0) {  
  sessionStorage.setItem('n', +sessionStorage.getItem('n') - 1);
  setTimeout(() => {
    location.reload();
  }, 30000);
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, it implements  the infinite number  of times

Comment: I see, I added a conditional to skip resetting n:=3. Also, try in a new tab or  run `sessionStorage.removeItem('n')`